# Docker container - node application - run issue

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I try to get my node application to run in a Docker container locally. I am using boot2docker.
The node application is structured as follow:
todolistdocker > todoapp > package.json + server.js + other folders (www,...)

My docker file is as per below:

```
# retrive the node docker image from bluemix node image
FROM registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode:latest

# retrieve the app source code
RUN git clone https://github.com/edevregille/todolistdocker.git

WORKDIR todolistdocker/todoapp

RUN npm install

# expose port
EXPOSE 6001

#launch the app
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

When I run the command

```
docker build -t manu/todoapp .
```

I get the following logs

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 323.6 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon
Step 0 : FROM registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode:latest
Pulling repository registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode
96ed152ebea0: Download complete 
83e4dde6b9cf: Download complete
b670fb0c7ecd: Download complete
29460ac93442: Download complete
d2a0ecffe6fa: Download complete
4bb543ba4efd: Download complete
edc4127366f7: Download complete
406f719b3e59: Download complete
18bafbc626ab: Download complete
ff1106e6dfc2: Download complete
4f7397e97d5c: Download complete
cf5c60a7eab1: Download complete
2af8b62ffa5f: Download complete
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry ice.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode:latest
---> 96ed152ebea0
Step 1 : RUN git clone https://github.com/edevregille/todolistdocker.git
 ---> Running in 9112add4fa4b
Cloning into 'todolistdocker'...
 ---> e9f4ac002a2c
Removing intermediate container 9112add4fa4b
Step 2 : WORKDIR todolistdocker/todoapp
  ---> Running in 8cbfb49a73cd
 ---> 68e04a64b395
Removing intermediate container 8cbfb49a73cd
Step 3 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 4f8643e83210
npm WARN package.json bluemix-todo-apps-node@0.1.0 No repository field.

> bson@0.1.5 install /todolistdocker/todoapp/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
> node install.js || (exit 0)

================================================================================
=                                                                                  =
=  Attempting to build bson c++ extension                                          =
 =   Windows: no build will be attempted as binaries are prepackaged                =
=   Unix: on failure the package will still install without the C++ extension  =
=                                                                               =
================================================================================
node-gyp clean
node-gyp configure build
make[1]: Entering directory     `/todolistdocker/todoapp/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/m ongodb/node_modules/bson/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bson.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bson.node: Finished
  COPY Release/bson.node
make[1]: Leaving directory     `/todolistdocker/todoapp/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/m    ongodb/node_modules/bson/build'
child process exited with code 0
ports@1.1.0 node_modules/ports

expect.js@0.3.1 node_modules/expect.js

underscore@1.6.0 node_modules/underscore

q@1.0.1 node_modules/q

nopt@2.2.1 node_modules/nopt
└── abbrev@1.0.7

coffee-script@1.7.1 node_modules/coffee-script
└── mkdirp@0.3.5

mocha@1.17.1 node_modules/mocha
├── diff@1.0.7
├── growl@1.7.0
├── commander@2.0.0
├── debug@2.2.0 (ms@0.7.1)
├── mkdirp@0.3.5
├── jade@0.26.3 (commander@0.6.1, mkdirp@0.3.0)
└── glob@3.2.3 (inherits@2.0.1, graceful-fs@2.0.3, minimatch@0.2.14)

cfenv@0.2.0 node_modules/cfenv
└── js-yaml@3.0.2 (argparse@0.1.16, esprima@1.0.4)

nano@4.7.1 node_modules/nano
├── underscore@1.5.2
├── errs@0.2.4
├── request@2.33.0 (forever-agent@0.5.2, aws-sign2@0.5.0, qs@0.6.6, oauth-     sign@0.3.0, tunnel-agent@0.3.0, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, mime@1.2.11, node-
10.1, form-data@0.1.4, hawk@1.0.0, tough-cookie@2.0.0)
└── follow@0.10.4 (debug@0.7.4, browser-request@0.3.3, request@2.30.0)
 ---> 21281d872464
Removing intermediate container 4f8643e83210
Step 4 : EXPOSE 6001
 ---> Running in 5d23a27e6c8c
 ---> 2b0b679643cf
Removing intermediate container 5d23a27e6c8c
Step 5 : CMD node todoapp/server.js
 ---> Running in 75cfaa646d09
 ---> 2346739e9613
Removing intermediate container 75cfaa646d09
Successfully built 2346739e9613
```

Then, I run docker

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker run -d -p 6001:6001 manu/todoapp
1ef378b6679cebb316db81b6c843d559180496ba798ea82f728a9f81eb64d757
```

And I don't have any container running...

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
docker@boot2docker:~$
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Did you have a look at the logs already? `docker logs <containerId>`

Comment: Have you tried overriding the default command at runtime ? Try running the container in interactive mode like this
docker run -it -p 6001:6001 manu/todoapp bash

Comment: I notice you are using the old IBM Containers Beta registry. That's not necessarily the cause of your issue, but the beta registry will go away very soon. You should switch to the now live service that uses registry.ng.bluemix.net, e.g.:

FROM registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode:latest

Comment: can you try docker ps -a to check if it was run?

Comment: Thanks, problem solved by running the docker logs (there was an issue with my database connection).

Answer (score 1):

The container probably shuts down because the node.js daemon cannot start or dies.

Start it in interactive mode with
docker -i -t [image name] /bin/bash 
and try your commands interactively to check the node.js daemon is starting fine